# power view with Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerview, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to publish sharepoint2016 website including Power View reports which created by SQL server services service (SSRS). there is top level site and bi center as sub-site; both are working fine but problem is that when I try to view the report it said the error:
"the web application at [url] could not be found. verify that you have typed the url correctly. if the url should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request url mapping to the intended application."I search about the error but It does not reach my target.
https://forums.asp.net/t/1970799.aspx?SQL+Reporting+Service+Runtime+Error+The+item+reports+Report1+cannot+be+found+rsItemNotFound+

note that the whole site is working fine in domain.
Please help...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late guys...

i found that Power shell of SP cannot execute any command related to SSRS
it just need to reinstall SSRS service compatible with SP2016. then every thing is fine.